# How to correctly implement a custom initializer for a subclassed NSManagedObject

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I am wondering what the correct way is to create my own initializer of a class that is subclassing NSManagedObject.

Currently I am initializing like this:

```
-(id)initWithXML:(TBXMLElement *)videoXML
{
    // Setup the environment for dealing with Core Data and managed objects
    HenryHubAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entityHubPieceVideo = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"HubPieceVideo" 
                                                           inManagedObjectContext:context];

    self = [[HubPieceVideo alloc] initWithEntity:entityHubPieceVideo insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context];
    // do stuff and then save

    NSError *error;
    if(![context save:&error]) 
    {
        NSLog(@"HubPiece video save context error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]); 
    }
}
```

Seems like [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918703/failed-to-call-designated-initializer-on-nsmanagedobject-class-item) others [also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556304/cocoa-touch-nsmanagedobject-exception-when-setting-a-property/1556370#1556370) do it this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found that the [NSManagedObject reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001171-223939) says:

> If you instantiate a managed object
>   directly, you must call the designated
>   initializer
>   (initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:).